# Removing rows on outer query when subquery returns null

Tags: mysql

After the select is executed, I am getting the error "unknown column 'points' in 'where clause'

How can I remove rows from the outer query that contain null records returned from a sub-query? (I need to use the sub-query, as I have another bunch of sub-queries that need to be run to return results I am after)

```
SELECT  
   s.student_name_first,
   s.student_name_last,
   (
   SELECT sum(i.points)
   FROM incidents i
   WHERE i.student = s.id
   ) AS points
FROM students s
WHERE points IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY s.id
```

I have also tried, with the same results

```
SELECT  
   s.student_name_first,
   s.student_name_last,
   (
   SELECT sum(i.points) AS points
   FROM incidents i
   WHERE i.student = s.id AND points IS NOT NULL 
   ) AS p
FROM students s
GROUP BY s.id
```

thanks in advance

---

Solution:

What I was looking for was **HAVING**

```
SELECT  
   s.student_name_first,
   s.student_name_last,
   (
   SELECT COALESCE(sum(i.incident_points),0)
   FROM incidents i
   WHERE i.student = s.id
   ) as points
FROM students s
GROUP BY s.id
HAVING points > 0
```

Comment: Reword "prevent null records being returned on a sub-query" part, as removing rows in outer query, containing nulls is not the same, as preventing sub-query from returning nulls.

Comment: Reworded, hope that helps

Comment: OK, thanks, I'm removing my answer as non-relevant to this form. Barmar's one will suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you can't use `SELECT` aliases in the `WHERE` clause, they have to be in `HAVING`.

But if you use an inner join, you won't get any null rows in the first place.

```
SELECT s.student_name_first,
       s.student_name_last,
       SUM(i.points) AS points
FROM students s
JOIN incidents i
ON i.student = s.id
GROUP BY s.id
```

Comment: Thanks! I was editing my question with the answer I found as you posted this :)